# How to reshape a Ruby array

Tags: ruby, arrays

Having an array

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

I want to reshape it to

```
a = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

I've had an impression that there was a specific method for this. I've just been through Array class reference, but failed to find it. Does anyone remember?

Comment: Don't forget to also check [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html).

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I forgot :-). I somehow stubbornly believed that I've seen it in the Array itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
a.each_slice(2).to_a # => [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Like this, for example:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
a.each_slice(2).to_a # => [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

Comment: Heck, that's why, it's in Enumerable :-)

Comment: Yeah, it is. Many array methods come from it :)

Comment: OK, thanks. I'll accept davidtrac, because he hit the enter button earlier :)

Comment: Hey, but my answer has example output! (*joking*)

Comment: I think output is very useful for answers like these. Submitted an edit request to davidrac's answer :-)